# How can i reset a query in a custom wordpress metabox

Tags: wordpress, meta

I'm working on this plugin for wordpress and i am stuck on a query that won't be reset.
In the following function:

```
function WPSM_artists_autocomplete(){

 $response = array();

 query_posts('post_type=artist&posts_per_page=-1');

  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
   $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();  
  $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'artist-icon');  
  $image_url = $image_url[0];  

  $response[] = array( get_the_ID() , get_the_title() , null, '<img src="'.$image_url.'" />'. get_the_title()); 
    endwhile; endif;

    wp_reset_query();

    // Write JSON file
 $output = json_encode($response);
 $data = WPSM_CACHE_DIR."/data.json";
 $fh = fopen($data, 'w') or die("can't open file");
 fwrite($fh, $output);
 fclose($fh);

 // Return JSON url
 echo WPSM_CACHE_URL."/data.json";
}
```

I use a query_posts to populate a metabox. But the wp_reset_query(); doesn't seem to work properly. This affects all other metaboxes and post related option. The global $post variable is set to the latest value of this query, and not the default value of the posts edit page.

I'd love to hear how to solve this plugin. Could use everything to get me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Cheers,

Ronny

Comment: Finally found someone with the same issue as me

Answer (score 6):

I came across this today and found a fix.

You will need to store the original $post before starting a new loop and then at the end of your function you will need to set it back.

Before you function assign $post to a temporary variable.

```
$original_query = $wp_query;
```

Then at the end of your function set it back.

```
   $wp_query = $original_query;
   wp_reset_postdata();
```

Not sure if the above works in your case as I was using a custom query.

I have posted my code below so you can have a look.

```
            global $wpdb;
            global $post;
            $originalpost = $post;

            $querydetails = "
                SELECT *
                FROM $wpdb->posts
                WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'projects'
                AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
                ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
             ";

             $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querydetails, OBJECT);

             if ($pageposts) {
                 foreach ($pageposts as $post) { 
                       setup_postdata($post);

                        $postID = get_the_ID();
                        echo '<option value="';
                        echo $postID . '"';
                        foreach ($meta as $m) {
                            if ($postID == $m) echo ' selected="selected" ';
                        }               
                        echo '>';
                        echo the_title();
                        echo '</option>';
                 }
            }

            echo "</select>";
            $this->show_field_end($field, $meta);
            $post = $originalpost;
```

Comment: I know I'm 2 years late to add this comment, but I wanted to say that it's still applicable. I created a custom loop inside a metabox, using WP-Query, and it was screwing up all my other custom postmeta calls. wp_reset_postdata did nothing at all. Storing the original and then reseting manually finally fixed it though. Thank you!

Comment: Jamie this is simply amazing. This is like a hidden answer :)

Comment: After almost 3 hours of poking around, this actually solved the issue I was facing. I was running a custom query in a metabox, and it was screwing up the global $post variable of the edit page. This is gold! Thanks for posting this response.

Comment: Whuuuuu I spun around for 3 hours... before understading my global $post was altered by and custom WP_Query made on meta-box.
I saved the global $post and did my stuff and works perfectly.
Thanks guy from 2020